# what wallet and payment methods to use in Africa?

Tags: mining

So my question is very simple :
I live in Morocco and I wanna know what coin-based websites support my country ?

Answer (score 0):

If I´m not wrong, you are asking for websites that sell/buy cryptocurrencies, right? Well, I used localbitcoins to find how to buy/sell bitcoins in my country. It helped me. https://localbitcoins.com/country/MA

Comment: yeah this sites shows that it supports my country... now the  question is how to link my wallet to this site ... I  mean how to exchange my currency from my wallet to sell it in this site... PS; am a beginner and I have no idea on this specific subject

Comment: Hi. So, you have to get that info from the trader you are going to choose. In my country, I got one that accepted bank transfer from the bank I have an account. I transfered money to the trader and trader sent the amount of bitcoins to my wallet. Some may accept credit card. It depends and each one has a fee. But be aware that the trader is going to transfer to the account inside localbitcoins website. And from there, you can transfer to your account if you have one in another wallet. And since you are a beginner, you should made a small transfer for the first time to learn first